# Angular Material Dialog rendering image every time when opened

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, angular-material, modal-dialog

I've successfully implemented an Angular Material Dialog for displaying speaker profiles on my webpage. The page features a list of speaker profiles, and upon clicking a profile, a modal opens to show detailed information, including elements like title, subtitle, image, and biography.

However, I've noticed that every time the modal is opened, the image reloads. I'm looking for a way to load the image only on the initial opening of the modal, as the speaker profile data is already available on the page.

Could someone provide guidance or an example using Angular Material Dialog to optimize the modal implementation and load the image only during the initial modal opening?

Excerpt from the code:

```
  openSpeakerModal(speaker: Speaker): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.DIALOG.open(PremiumEventSpeakersModalComponent, {
        data: {
          speaker: speaker,
        },
        backdropClass: 'cmp-filter-dialog-overlay',
        panelClass: 'cmp-filter-dialog-box',
        restoreFocus: true,
      })
        .afterClosed()
        .subscribe((data) => {
          if (data) {
          }
        });
    }, 0);
  }
```

```html
<div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal">
  <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__body">
    <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__left">
      <div
        class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__image img-position-bottom__content img-square"
      >
        <img
          alt=""
          width="200"
          height="200"
          [src]="speaker.domain + speaker.thumbnail"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__content">
        <h3
          class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__content__title dot-ellipsis"
        >
          {{ speaker.name }}
        </h3>
        <h5 class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__content__sub-title">
          {{ speaker.jobTitle }}
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div
        class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__connections social-connections"
      >
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let link of socials">
            <a
              [attr.href]="link.url"
              [class]="link.class"
              title=""
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener"
              [attr.aria-label]="link.label"
            ></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__right">
      <div
        class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__desc"
        [innerHTML]="speaker.biography | safeHtml"
      ></div>

      <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__sessions">
        <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__sessions-label">
          Sessions:
        </div>
        <ul class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__sessions-link">
          <li *ngFor="let session of speaker.sessions">
            <a
              [href]="session['page-url'] + '?sid=' + session['page-id']"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener"
              >{{ session.name }}</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__close">
      <button
        class="cmp-premium-event-speaker-modal__close-button"
        mat-button
        mat-dialog-close
      >
        <i class="icon-remove" aria-label="Close"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share more details about PremiumEventSpeakersModalComponent?

Comment: It is a static angular material modal, it has few details to show related to speaker.

Comment: I would like to help you but I need to understand the html in modal component, if you could provide a similar example on stackblitz or codesandbox, I am willing to help you.

Comment: @DiogoMachado added html for reference. Also I was trying in stackblitz not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You need to check the server that is hosting the images and the strategy via cache, and if you URL was different each time you open the dialog, the browser will understand as a new resource.